# Dependency conflicts in scala multi moduled projects

Tags: scala, dependencies, multi-module

I have below structure for the project.

```
project
 |_build.properties
 |_plugins.sbt
Core
Module1
Module2
build.sbt
```

In Module1 and Module2, I use the same dependency in different versions. Then I aggregate the 2 modules with Core module. Then one dependency is getting evicted by another version. How do I keep both dependency versions?

Update: The expected dependency tree is as follows:

```
core_1.0-SNAPSHOT
-module1_1.0
--org.milyn:milyn-smooks-core:1.1
-module2_1.0
--org.milyn:milyn-smooks-core:1.5.2

module1_1.0-SNAPSHOT
-org.milyn:milyn-smooks-core:1.1

module2_1.0-SNAPSHOT
-org.milyn:milyn-smooks-core:1.5.2
```

And, what I getting is as follows:

```
    core_1.0-SNAPSHOT
    -module1_1.0
    --org.milyn:milyn-smooks-core:1.1 (evicted by 1.5.2)
    -module2_1.0
    --org.milyn:milyn-smooks-core:1.5.2
    
    module1_1.0-SNAPSHOT
    -org.milyn:milyn-smooks-core:1.1
    
    module2_1.0-SNAPSHOT
    -org.milyn:milyn-smooks-core:1.5.2
```

How can I disregard the eviction?

Comment: You need to shade them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 99% of cases you don't want to have two versions of the same dependency. Assuming they contain same classes (as in the same name), it will cause runtime errors as only one version will be loaded (first come, first loaded).

What you likely want to do is:

- either let the eviction do its work (it should pick up most recent version)
- or, define the same version across all your modules
- or, define some `dependencyOverrides` in your "Core" module to force a version (which can be the one of "Module1", "Module2", or even another one)

Comment: In my case, Module 1 uses org.milyn:milyn-smooks-core:1.1 and the Module 2 uses org.milyn:milyn-smooks-core:1.5.2. Those 2 are used for different types of CSV transformations. In Core module. I have 2 tests to run, each on Module 1 and Module 2. In order to run those two tests, I need both 1.1 and 1.5.2 versions of the same dependency. But since dependency 1.1 is evicted by 1.5.2, I get "NoSuchMethodError" exception.

Comment: How will the core module be used? People will use it but only use module1 transformation or module2 transformation?

Comment: Module1 or Module2 is used based on the transformation type. (Yes, we can't use both modules at once) But, still when I try to execute tests, one test gets failed because both modules use same version of the library. (I update the question with dependency tree)

Comment: If in the end _we cant' use both modules at once_ as you say, I would split the core module in 2 then. Or maybe move the tests out to 2 différents "core_tests" modules

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion which did not come across my mind until you said. I'll try having 2 different core modules. :)